# I want to convert individual list into one list

Tags: python

I have a list of this format ['a']['b']['c'] ,I need it in this format ['a','b','c']
An individual list with strings as the datatype and I need these strings in one list

Comment: "['a']['b']['c']" isn't a thing. Please show an unambiguous, reproducible example what your data really looks like.

Comment: a=['a']
b=['b']
c=a+b
print(c)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
list_a = [ ['a'],['b'],['c'] ]
list_b = [a[0] for a in list_a]
```

It'll solve your problem.